# How can i support my HTML5 template RTL (Right to Left)

Tags: html, css, sass, right-to-left

I want to my HTML5 template support RTL (Right to Left). But I do not know how to do it. If someone helps me, then I will know it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you have to setup `dir=rtl` in your html for this like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

Add dir="rtl" to the html tag any time the overall document direction is right-to-left. This sets the base direction for the whole document.

No dir attribute is needed for documents that have a base direction of left-to-right, since this is the default.

Here is one very nice article to achieve RTL in your HTML template : https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Answer (score 1):

you apply

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

You should apply rtl css  file (framework) ,   from CDN otherwise download locally and give the path of file regarding in  your working file.